# Python SalesForce FuelSDK TLS - which version

Tags: fuel-sdk, tls

Recently SalesForce Marketing Cloud announced retirement of the TLS 1.0 based connections effective early August this year.

I am using Python SalesForce FuelSDK to manage my API connections and operations with SFMC.

1. How can I be sure that I am relying on TLS 1.2 and my APIs will stay operational after TLS 1.0 is retired by SFMC?
2. Is FuelSDK supported and will continue to support TLS 1.2?
3. Any pointers?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to my own question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226168/how-to-check-which-tls-protocol-is-using-the-fuel-sdk-for-java) , maybe this will hint you on how you can check that, but basically, you should be looking at how your framework is creating your requests and if it is in TLS1.2.

Finally, you could just do what i did and use wireshark and see the protocol in which the request travels.

Answer (score 0):

TLS is a transport mechanism (communications protocol), so FuelSDK is unaffected, so long as the python libraries you're using are up to date... which version of python are you running?  Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

If you're using an out of date set of SSL python libraries, then they won't be able to connect. Unfortunately, without knowing more about your particular setup, this is a challenging question to answer.