# How to check which TLS protocol is using the FUEL-SDK for java

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, tls, sdk

Salesforce Marketing cloud recently announced the retirement of the TLS 1.0 based connections effective early August this year, and they published a [Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270626&language=en_US&type=1) with useful information and some guidelines for the matter, but in that article they talk about integrations with the API (REST/SOAP) but not with the SDKs (even though, that's just a wrapper of the afore mentioned).

I'm using the [FuelSDK-Java](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/) to integrate my backend with Salesforce Marketing Cloud and i would like to check which TLS protocol it is using to connect with.

How/where can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not the Fuel-SDK what we should look at but the JDK version we are using.

Java 8 use TLS1.2 as [default](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https) for connections, and i double checked it with wireshark while doing request to SFMC using the fuel-sdk for java.